# How to convert Latitude and longitude to Location name

Tags: java, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

How can I get an address or a locality name from the geo-coordinates (latitude, longitude) using an API in Java? Is there any reverse geocoder available in Java?

Comment: You will need to use a reverse geocoding service. You can read more about the API that google provides: [Google API Reverse Geocoding](http://nicogoeminne.googlepages.com/documentation.html)

Comment: You can find other providers as well, but for me Google was the most accurate

Comment: this answer can also help on how-to implement
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6480558/492918 *...<br/>
[Social Coding @ AspiroTV](http://github.com/AspiroTV)*

Comment: Fails the fundamental test of "what have you tried?"