# List of GeoCordinates to Postal/Zip Code

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Is there a publically available List or a database that has geo-coordinates to Postal/Zip Code mapping ?

Comment: Tony, this is called reverse geocoding and I beleive there are many answers around this tag.

Comment: Puddleglum has answered this on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471/zip-code-database) (see the List of Free ZIP Code Sources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google Maps API for reverse geocoding. Check this out [Google Maps Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) and a [working sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-v2-samples/blob/gh-pages/geocoder/reverse.html).

Also you can check out earlier questions: [How to convert Latitude and longitude to Location name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025925/how-to-convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-location-name)

Answer (score 1):

For what country? Some countries have publically available databases but most don't.

Commercial databases often carries a hefty price and an unfriendly license. There are efforts underway by [OpenStreeMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) and [FreeThePostCode](http://www.freethepostcode.org/) (UK) that you might want to check out for more information.

Wikiepedia also has a pretty good article on postal [codes in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) with lots of information.

[This page at about.com](http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/zipcodedatabase.htm) talks about a zip code database for the US that was produced in 1999 by the Census Bureau (rendering it public domain according to US-laws). A lot has happened since 1999 though but it may be worth a look.

Comment: Mark, For US and Canada, although I hit upon couple of gov-ca googles, non provide a concrete list.
Thanks - tony

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing free for commercial use -- not even Bing, Yahoo, or Google. See my answer on this other post:

[How to let users choose their town, so my app can know coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708465/how-to-let-users-choose-their-town-so-my-app-can-know-coordinates/3709820#3709820)

Comment: Try this..it's free and it's for zipcode/postal boundaries..returns polygons,points for zipcode boundaries in geojosn. https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/boundaries-io

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you are in the world... For the united states, I believe the information is available without restriction. In the UK, you can license the "Postal Address File" from the Royal Mail, but it's expensive.

I found someone selling the Zip Code database here:

http://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code-database.asp

But you need to be aware that the information changes over time - as new properties are built...

Answer (score 0):

If you have money and you want to pay for it Navteq and TeleAtlas will also sell you the data. They cover quite a bit of the globe but not all of it. There also might be the data in Open Street Map (OSM). I would reccomend looking there first.