# How to let users choose their town, so my app can know coordinates

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation, maps

I am starting my first Open Source ASP.NET project in C#. Data that Web app is going to show is in close relation with geographic coordinates of towns.

Now I want to implement user interface where user of web app can choose a desired town and submit form, and behind scene i want to get coordinates of chosen town, so I can make calculations.

Now I wondering is there some free services or library, which can I implement to get wanted results?

Does Google's Maps provide this feature or there is other services with databases of towns around worlds and theirs coordinates?

Comment: Something like this http://www.itouchmap.com/latlong.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Microsoft's Bing Maps API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If Google have it it will be [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html).  When I was tasked with this once we simply downloaded some SQL off the web.  Not sure if [this was the exact site](http://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm) but it was something similar. Whack it in your database and query when needed.

Comment: Thanx on link, unfortunately this site offers only PO codes and it is only in UK, I am targeting the whole word in my Web APP

Answer (score 1):

Be really careful with these APIs. Read the Terms carefully, as they have some interesting stipulations. To boil it down -- don't try using it for commercial purposes. Google states that you should never cache any of your results (which prohibits geocoding addresses and storing them in your database. I have some old Google code that I did as a proof-of-concept that allowed me to geocode from the server-side via their JSON call.

If you're looking for a REAL adventure, you can get the TIGER-LINE data from the Census bureau and do the geocode math yourself. [Semaphore](http://www.semaphorecorp.com/home/contact.html) has a great, cheap product for cleaning up addresses and looking up TIGER-LINE stats. 32-bit only.

Comment: Good warning regarding "Commercial Use". I doubt if "free + commercial use" even exists. Here is some good insight if you want free to near free and can skimp on the quality  [free & cheap postal data](http://greatdata.com/resources). regards