# Android: Does Address(from GeoCode) have fixed format?

Tags: android, location, street-address

I need to determine the address for a geo location, so I used GeoCoder and Address, I tried to print an Address object and got the following:

(for privacy reason, I used some fake data, but the data I received on my device is real)

Address[addressLines=[0:"123 ABC St",1:"Melbourne VIC 1234",2:"Australia"],feature=123,admin=Victoria,sub-admin=null,locality=Melbourne,thoroughfare=ABC St,postalCode=1234,countryCode=AU,countryName=Australia,hasLatitude=true,latitude=-123.321,hasLongitude=true,longitude=123.321,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]

Now I'm wondering, can I assume that:

1. address line index 0 is always the street address?
2. and index 1 and to is the suburb, state, postcode pair, and index 2 is the country?
3. "feature" is actually the street number(ie 123)?
4. "admin" is state?

If the format is NOT fixed, how do I get address information?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the format is fixed and you should not rely on the array indexes. From the docs:

> The amount of detail in a reverse
>   geocoded location description may
>   vary, for example one might contain
>   the full street address of the closest
>   building, while another might contain
>   only a city name and postal code. The
>   Geocoder class requires a backend
>   service that is not included in the
>   core android framework.

The geocoding service is implemented by the Google Maps service which runs in the backgroind I believe. You should use  [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) class to fetch the elements of the address that you require.

Comment: Yes I am using the Address class, the String in my post is actually returned by Address object's toString() method, I need to know which method(getThoroughfare(), getFeature(), or what) returns street number and name. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you will have to find that out through trial and error. The address information returned by the geocoder depends upon the country/location. Something for the US might be something different for other countries. And some locations do not return street numbers at all.

Comment: But how do I do it? I cannot travel through all places in the world to test it.

Comment: And you can also try the Google Maps API reverse geocoder. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that may help.

**-> using GeoCoder**

```
    String currentAddress = "";

    try {
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> adds = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude
                        , longitude
                        , 1);

        if (adds!=null && adds.size()>0) {
             Address add = adds.get(0);
             int max = add.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
             if (max!=-1) {
                   for (int i=0; i<max;i++)
                   currentAddress += add.getAddressLine(i) + " ";
             }
        }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
     Log.w(TAG, "geocoding_fromAndroid->"+ex.toString());
     currentAddress = "";
}
```

Please keep in mind, GeoCoder is NOT implemented in all Android devices :| in this case, you can **use Google API directly**

-> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Thanks, but how do I determine is there GeoCoder available on a device?

Comment: @hzxu You can determine the availability of GeoCoder in two ways. <br/>1) when u get exception <br/>2) using this func which is available from api level 9 onwards -> [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent())